# how to share Models folder between two (yii2 basic) applications

Tags: php, model, yii2

i have two `yii2 basic` application that use same database.
my current structure is :

```
/www
  /Project A
      /components
      /config
      /controller
      /models
      /...

  /Project B
      /components
      /config
      /controller
      /models
      /...
```

but i want to create this structure

```
/www
  /Project A
      /components
      /config
      /controller
      /...

  /Project B
      /components
      /config
      /controller
      /...

  /shared
      /models
```

how i can do it?

Comment: although they share same database but do they share a same domain , or are they being hosted at 2 different domains? i would suggest to follow the `advance-app` structure and import both of the `apps` under the same root

Comment: use yii-app-advanced and put shared models in common. by default there are 2 applications (frontend and backend) but you can add as many as you like

Comment: You can create a `module` and manage it as an external dependency for both projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Put your models into the `/path/to/www/shared/models` and put them into `shared/models` namespace

2) Set `@shared` alias in your config for both applications to point into `/path/to/www/shared` like this

```
return [
    // ...
    'aliases' => [
        '@shared' => '/path/to/www/shared',

    ],
];
```

Then you should be able to use the models same way as if they were directly in your app.

You can read more about autoloading [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-autoloading) and more about defining aliases [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-aliases#defining-aliases)